# Python IndexError: list index out of range with CSV file

Tags: python-3.x, csv, twitter, sentiment-analysis

I am trying to read the contents of a .CSV file of data from Twitter to perform some sentiment analysis. The file has four columns which should be pulled but I am having some trouble with the following block of code:

```
tweets = []

with open('tweets.csv','r', encoding = 'utf-8', newline='') as csvfile:
    reader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',')
    next(reader)
    for row in reader:
        tweet = dict()
        tweet['user'] = row[0]
        tweet['date'] = row[1]
        tweet['type'] = row[2]
        tweet['orig'] = row[3]
```

When running the script I receive the error

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "analysis.py", line 46, in <module>
    tweet['user'] = row[0]
    IndexError: list index out of range
```

Looking around the sight I see this is a common problem but as I'm fairly new to Python I'm unsure how to implement a fix, or what I'm doing wrong.

**EDIT** I have discovered if I manually go into the .CSV file and delete the empty lines between rows, everything works fine. So I guess the question is, how would I best implement this?

Comment: What does it give you if you try printing `row`?

Comment: I'm a newbie with Python so unsure if this is correct, but if I try it I receive

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "analysis.py", line 44, in <module>
    next(reader)
StopIteration

Comment: Answer to edit : You can just keep a check saying `if(len(row)==4): tweet=dict()...`

Comment: That all works fine now, thank you for your patience!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Amended code the the following and problem solved.

```
    for row in reader:
        if (len(row) == 4):
            tweet = dict()
            tweet['user'] = row[0]
            tweet['date'] = row[1]
            tweet['type'] = row[2]
            tweet['orig'] = row[3]
```

Comment: You really should repair your input file instead; it's not valid CSV.